# How to add a checkmark to cells in UITableView (using a custom UITableViewCell subclass and dequeueReusableCell)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell, accessorytype

I would like to add checkmarks to my Table View cells. I would think to just implement `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` in my `didSelectRowAt` method, but I can't get this to work when using a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Custom cell:

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableLabel: UILabel!
    
    var arrayOneToDisplay:ArrayOne?
    let arrayOne = ArrayOne()
    
    func displayTable(_ currentArrayOne:ArrayOne) {
        
        // Keep a reference to the cell
        arrayOneToDisplay = currentArrayOne
        
        // Get the Table Cells data
        var tableCell = arrayOne.tableCells
        
        // Set the instructionLabel
        tableLabel.text = currentArrayOne.tableCells![0]
        
    }
```

ViewController:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // Make sure the array contains at least 1 item
        guard arrayOne.count > 0 else {
            return 0
        }
        
        // Return the number of items for this array
        let currentArrayOne = arrayOne[currentArrayOneIndex!]
        
        if currentArrayOne.tableCells != nil {
            return currentArrayOne.tableCells!.count
        }
        else {
            return 0
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Get a cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
        
        // Get the instruction that the tableView is asking about
        let tableLabel = cell.tableLabel
        
        if tableLabel != nil {
            
            let currentArrayOne = arrayOne[currentArrayOneIndex!]
            
            if currentArrayOne.tableCells != nil && indexPath.row < currentArrayOne.tableCells!.count {
                // Set the text for the label
                tableLabel!.text = currentArrayOne.tableCells![indexPath.row]
            }
        }
        
        // Return the cell
        return cell

    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        

    }

}
```

When I try to implement `cell.accessoryType` in the ViewController, Xcode doesn't recognize `accessoryType`. I believe it's because my methods are for `UITableView` and not `UITableViewCell`, so the added wrinkle of using a custom cell is causing some confusion for me. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your `accessoryType` in the `cellForRowAt` method, try to rewrite it as this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell

        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        
        guard let arrayOneIndex = currentArrayOneIndex, arrayOneIndex < arrayOne.count else { return cell }

        let currentArrayOne = arrayOne[arrayOneIndex]

        guard let tableCells = currentArrayOne.tableCells, indexPath.row < tableCells.count else { return cell }

        cell.tableLabel.text = tableCells[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! `cell.accessoryType` is working for me now. It just wasn't auto-filling in Xcode (which is what made me stumped).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, your approach is completely wrong. Never use a **view** as a data source type. Don't.

Create a **model**, this is a simple example with `name` and `isSelected` properties

```
struct Model {
    let name : String
    var isSelected = false
}
```

and in **controller** `ViewController` declare a data source array containing `Model` instances

```
var arrayOne = [Model(name: "Foo"), Model(name: "Bar"), Model(name: "Baz")]
```

In the extension in `numberOfRows` just return the number of items in the array (your `guard` expression makes no sense at all), in `cellForRow` set the checkmark depending on `isSelected` and in `didSelect` toggle the `isSelected` property and reload the row.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOne.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Get a cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
        
        // Get the item of the data source array
        let item = arrayOne[indexPath.row]
        
        // update the view
        cell.tableLabel = item.name
        cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none   
        
        // Return the cell
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // toggle isSelected of the row in the model
        arrayOne[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
      
        // reload the row to update the view
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)   
    }

}
```

In the custom cell declare only the outlet, nothing else

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableLabel: UILabel!
        
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that **model** and **view** are always in sync.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do have a data model that I've been using but I will look into adding more/all of my data into it.

Comment: Better to override the `TableCell`
 `isSelected` property. `override var isSelected: Bool { didSet { accessoryType = isSelected ? .checkmark : .none } }` Then you can do `cell.isSelected = item.isSelected`. Or even better add a `showViewModel` method to your custom cell and move the code out of your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you try to do. The usual way for table view is not to save tableviewcell in array. The model-view-controller (MVC) way is to save the contents of the cells (text, images, checkedOrNotChecked) in an array of struct or object  inside the viewcontroller (the array is the model). Then in CellForRow, set the content of the cell with the array[indexPath.row] element and if checkedOrNotCheckindicator set cell.accessoryType to checkmark (the cell is the view).
In didSelectRow , you just set the checkOrNotCheck indicator of indexPath.row element and then reload the table view or just reload the cell at indexPath.
Thé ViewController is the controller in MVC

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful for understanding.